# Azure API Management ARM template: skuproperties cannot be null

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I'm trying to provision the following API Management via ARM, with the following template (note specifically the apiVersion date of 2016-07-07). This results in the error:

> Invalid parameter: Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: skuproperties

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "apimSettings": {
        "type": "object",
        "defaultValue": {
            "sku": "Developer",
            "skuCount": "1",
            "publisherName": "",
            "publisherEmail": ""
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "apiManagementServiceName": "[concat('apim', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
},
"resources": [{
    "apiVersion": "2016-07-07",
    "name": "[variables('apiManagementServiceName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
    "properties": {
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('apimSettings').sku]",
            "capacity": "[parameters('apimSettings').skuCount]"
        },
        "publisherEmail": "[parameters('apimSettings').publisherEmail]",
        "publisherName": "[parameters('apimSettings').publisherName]"
    }
}],
"outputs": {
    "apimUri" : {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[reference(variables('apiManagementServiceName'))]"
    }
}
```

}

The [schema for that version of API Management](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2016-07-07/Microsoft.ApiManagement.json) doesn't show 'skuProperties'. Note, the deployment works if I use the old version 2014-02-14.  I also noted that the [deployment template schema](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json) refers to the newer API Management schema.

Clearly it wants "skuproperties" but how would I know what to provide there?

Answer (score 0):

this is how you use it:

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
        "sku": {
            "name": "Developer",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "name": "[parameters('name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-10-10",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "publisherEmail": "[parameters('adminEmail')]",
            "publisherName": "[parameters('orgName')]"
        }
    }
```

This is the [description of the API Management API model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apimanagementservices). As you can see it uses 2016-10-10 and the object similar to what I've described. That's why its working that way.

Comment: yes, this does work, but the question was about the 2016-07-07 version which, presumably, comes with additional functionality.  Try running the above with that as the apiVersion.

Comment: also, http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2016-10-10/Microsoft.ApiManagement.json is a 404; so why is that apiVersion valid?

Comment: I'm not a microsoft employee, I'm not familiar with the backend code\logic they have. I've told you how its done, i don't know why its done this way. don't use 2017-07-07 api version, that's it.

Comment: I didn't quite get you previous response. I've updated the question. ARM template schema is garbage. don't look at it. look at the actual rest api schema. thats the only thing that matters @JimO'Neil

Comment: @JimO'Neil You need to move ```"sku": {
            "name": "Developer",
            "capacity": 1
        },``` outside of ```properties``` scope as @4c74356b41 mentioned. I'm using the version ```2017-03-01``` and had the same issue. What is really crappy that the schema is valid even if ```sku``` is in the ```properties```.